# Encounter issues when enable change data capture (CDC) on SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I want to enable change data capture for the database and table I created.

First, I did not see any "System Tables" in the database I created. Is it an issue?

Second, I was able to enable CDC on the database and table I created, following the below commands. After CDC is enabled, I can see the function `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_xxx`. However, I can't find any CDC tables created under "System Tables".

These are the commands that I executed successfully:

```
mssql> create database x;
mssql> use x;
mssql> create table dbo.y ...;

mssql> exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;
OK

mssql> select name, is_cdc_enabled from sys.databases where is_cdc_enabled=1;
name     is_cdc_enabled
-------  --------------
x  true          

1 row(s) returned


EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table \
@source_schema = N'dbo', \
@source_name = N'y', \
@role_name = NULL, \
@supports_net_changes = 0;
OK

mssql> select name, is_tracked_by_cdc from sys.tables where is_tracked_by_cdc =1;
name     is_tracked_by_cdc
-------  -----------------
y  true             

1 row(s) returned
```

I followed this article to enable CDC:
https://malapatidatabase.wordpress.com/category/change-data-capture/page/2/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `select * from sys.tables where schema_id = schema_id('cdc')`

Comment: thanks Dale. I was able to find all the cdc related tables under cdc schema. somehow they did not show up in UI.